# IEEE 754 binary interchange floating-point format: why exponent is stick to the left and not to the right?

Tags: binary, ieee-754

Why in IEEE 754 binary interchange floating-point format the exponent is stick to the left (just after the sign) and not to the right?

In other words why current binary interchange floating-point format is like this:

```
sign | exponent | significand
```

and not like this:

```
significand | exponent | sign
```

or like this:

```
sign | significand | exponent
```

Reason of asking: It seems that *if the exponent will stick to the right*, then it will be possible to implement some backend compiler optimizations (using some HW instructions which use immediate values) w.r.t. comparisons where the 2nd operand is of a particular cases (e.g. 1.0: sign is 0, exponent is 0x3ff, significand is 0).

Extra questions: will binary interchange floating-point format (tend to) be reversed on big-endian systems?

UPD20210902: The answer is "to maintain the lexicographical ordering of real numbers, which facilitates sorting of real numbers". Relevant article: V. Rajaraman, IEEE Standard for Floating Point Numbers, RESONANCE, January 2016:
[image]

Quote:

> Sorting real numbers may also be carried out by IUs as biased exponent are the most significant bits. This ensures lexicographical ordering of real numbers; the significand need not be considered as a fraction.

Comment: Exponent on the left results in the floating-point represented values having the same order as the binary values (the values when the bits are interpreted as binary numerals), except they are flipped for the sign bit. This facilitates comparisons on systems without hardware floating-point support. I am not positive that was the driving motivation. I do not see what useful optimizations are enabled by switching the significand and exponent positions.

Comment: Re “will binary interchange floating-point format (tend to) be reversed on big-endian systems?”: The binary interchange format is a binary interchange format. It is for interchanging binary, which you do by using the same format on different systems. The format is specified by specifying how floating-point data are mapped to strings of bits. Getting the bit strings between one system and another is somebody else’s job.